# PHP TCPDF sign PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, signature

I would like to sign a PDF using TCPDF library.
I found an example at https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/ .

The only problem is how to get a valid certificate for this.

I trued to contact some certificate authorities, but they can issue certificates on a hardware (USB token) that can be used to manually sign documents.
I would like this process to be automatic done on the server side, so users can download signed certificates.

So question is: Is this possible? And if Yes, is there a certificate authority that can issue this type of certificate?

Comment: Are you open for alternative solutions than TCPDF?

Comment: PDF is generated using TCPDF, but if there is a library that can just sign PDF, it should be OK

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any CA that issues software certificates which validates through the [AATL](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) (it requires that the key is stored on a secure hardware device and cannot be extracted). There are some information floating around that some CAs are issuing qualified seals (kind of company certificates) as software certificate which validate through the [EUTL](https://helpx.adobe.com/document-cloud/kb/european-union-trust-lists.html), but we didn't make it to any official quotation at any CA until now.

There's a [blog post from 2015](https://linkwi.se/gr-el/blog/blog-inner/qualified-electronic-signatures-pdf-php/), where someone used OpenSSL CLI calls in TCPDF to get this working with a certificate and key on an USB token.

Today there are several cloud services which offers key management systems which will store the key on a secure hardware device:

- [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/key-vault/)
- [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/)
- [Google Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs)

To get a valid certificate for your key you need to attest the issuing certificate authority that your private key is created and stored on such a secure hardware device. This is only possible for Google Cloud KMS in an automated way at the moment (which may change in the future - see e.g. [here](https://github.com/pkic/remote-key-attestation) for an overview of services and devices that support such attestation).

For services which doesn't support an automated attestation the issuing certificate authority may offer different attestation ways. Some allows you to create a screen recording of the key creation ceremony. Others requires a remotely-witnessed key pair generation ceremony through a web meeting. They may add a fee for this kind of attestation.

We ([Setasign](https://www.setasign.com)) offer a commercial PDF signature solution in PHP, named [SetaPDF-Signer](https://setasign.com/signer), which comes with modules for all listed key management systems. You can see them in action here:

- [SetaPDF-Signer demo for Azure Key Vault](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/azure-key-vault/)
- [SetaPDF-Signer demo for AWS KMS](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/aws-kms/)
- [SetaPDF-Signer demo for Google Cloud KMS](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/google-cloud-kms/)

In the demos we create LTV (long term validation) enabled signatures with certificates issued by [Ensured](https://www.ensured.com/). The attestation was done by screen recordings of the key creation ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you read the link you have posted?

From the source code (below the PDF):

```
/*
NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
 - To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
*/
```

Self-signed certificate is perfectly legit. Other than that you can buy a 1-year certificate at any trusted provider (X509 certificate, same as used for SSL).

Lastly: you don't hand out the certificate... you sign a PDF with the secret key and verify with the public key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see any problems generating a certificate. The only question is: if I send PDF to another person, will PDF reader treat this certificate as valid when user will open the file?

Comment: Sure... but does the user trusts you if you used a self-signed certificate?